# iOS 7 Stop Autorotate

Tags: ios, iphone

I'm trying to lock orientation of my entire app to portrait modes, so I changed the `info.plist`, to this:

[image]

However, if I rotate the simulator or even my real device, the view still rotates. Any explanation for this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to implement this in your ViewController:

For iOS 6 and up:

```
#ifdef __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 60000

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}

#endif
#endif
```

For iOS under 6:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    BOOL returnBool = YES;

    if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) {
        returnBool = YES;
    }
    else if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
        returnBool = YES;
    }
    else if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {
        returnBool = NO;
    }
    else if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
        returnBool = NO;
    }
    else {
        returnBool = NO;
    }

    return returnBool;
}
```

The pre-processor statements are to make sure the method __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED exists

```
#ifdef __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED
```

and the second one:

```
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 60000
```

is to make sure the iOS version running on the device is 6 and up because the methods in the pre-processor statements do not exist on versions under iOS 6.
It will crash on iOS under 6 without the pre-processor statements.

Comment: Could you please explain the peculiar pre-processor statements?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I had the same question as @Josiah, as well as some of my own: 1.I'm getting `missing context for method declaration` error for `-shouldAutorotate` and `-(preferredInterface..)`

Comment: EDIT: Solved the first problem, had another question: Will Apple accept this? When I was typing in some of your methods, they weren't showing up in the Autocomplete, so I'm guessing they are private?

Comment: Josiah - the pre-processor statements are to make sure the method __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED exists and the second one
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 60000
is to make sure the iOS version running on the device is 6 and up because the methods in the pre-processor statements do not exist on versions under iOS 6. It will crash on iOS under 6 without the pre-processor statements.

Comment: Carpetfizz - these methods are documented by Apple and I submitted a few apps with these, so don't worry :)